# rails service object with current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise and have created a service object - everything works as expected and perfectly. However I want to know how I would include the current_user? as the moment I have to always pass in the current_user or user_signed_in? variables which is annoying when I am using the same methods in different classes and views how would I go about doing this?

Currently I have this for testing:

```
class User
    class GetStart
        attr_reader :current_user

        def initialize(user)
            @current_user = user
            p current_user
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: it should be `@current_user = user` in the initialize method, otherwise your `attr_reader` returns nothing.

Comment: Fix per last comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`current_user` is usually a helper method of ApplicationController which means it will only be accessible within your controllers and views. This is a good thing -- your service object has no business accessing `current_user` directly since current_user is created from information passed in the request/session which is a concern of the controller.

In my opinion, your approach is correct, it's preferable to pass your user object in as an external object (i.e. dependency injection) than directly couple it to method within a separate object. After all, does your service object need to know or care whether `user` is from the session?

Also, as was mentioned, keep in mind that `attr_reader` creates an instance variable for the class, so you should have `@current_user = user`.